# Sharing dynamic URLS

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I have a music website which streams music from youtube, vevo and other media sites. 
The thing is, even if i define t=`<?php echo $name; ?>`

It will display the name of the song on the sharer.php linkbar, facebook still wont render the correct title.

you can try and see what im trying to explain here:

http://www.soundwavez.net/video/fWNaR-rxAic

If you click share, in the link bar, it will show the title of the song, defined as: t=

But facebook wont scrape the actual title and place it on the shared post.

This is what i do:  `<meta property="og:title" content="<?php echo $name; ?>" />`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding Open Graph data in the page header.
http://ogp.me/

Here is an example:

```
<html prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">
<head>
    ...
    <meta property="og:title" content="SONG_TITLE">
    <meta property="og:type" content="music.song">
    <meta property="og:url" content="PAGE_URL">
    <meta property="og:image" content="ALBUM_COVER">
</head>
```

Comment: Hi, I just checked the first comment, and it didnt display the php i pasted. I echo name$ for the title in the og tags, but that has no response.

Comment: I just clicked on the link from your question. I see that you added the og:title attribute but the content is empty. You'll need to fix that in your code. Also, the Open Graph protocol requires four attributes: title, type, url, and image.

Comment: Ah, I see, Maybe og dont render php calls?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with your PHP code. Make sure the $name variable (the song name) is set before you try to echo it out. If your page header is inside a function, make sure that function has access to the $name variable. I hope that helps. I can't see your code, so I'm just making some guesses.